# How to upgrade _RICHEDIT_VER (riched20.dll) to version 3 or higher

Tags: c++, visual-studio, version, richedit

I am using for a C++ LIbrary WTL10 from Microsoft. If i want to compile it in VS19, i will get an error, that says WTL10 requieres Richedit version 3 or higher.

Here is the code from **atlctrls.h**

```
#if (_RICHEDIT_VER < 0x0300)
    #error WTL10 requires RichEdit version 3 or higher
#endif
```

But i got in **afxwin.h** :

```
#define _RICHEDIT_VER 0x0210
```

How can i upgrade it? I never upgraded dlls manually, so i wanted to ask here and i could not find help with google for richedit.

Answer (score 2):

------- Found a solution ------

You have to insert

```
#undef _RICHEDIT_VER
```

after

```
<afxwin.h>
```

Like this:

```
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#undef _RICHEDIT_VER
```

RICHEDIT.H will define_RICHEDIT_VER to the newest version

Comment: It's a fine work around. It's regretful that seems no one uses MFC anymore.

Comment: I agree that new projects may not be using MFC. But there is still active MFC development going on as those projects were started 15-25 years back. And migrating to other tech is expensive.